# How to get a layer from a caffe model using torch

Tags: python, lua, caffe, torch

In python when I want to get the data from a layer using caffe I have the following code

```
    input_image = caffe.io.load_image(imgName)
    input_oversampled = caffe.io.resize_image(input_image, self.net.crop_dims)
    prediction = self.net.predict([input_image])
    caffe_input = np.asarray(self.net.preprocess('data', prediction))
    self.net.forward(data=caffe_input)
    data = self.net.blobs['fc7'].data[4] // I want to get this value in lua
```

Hoever when I'm using torch I'm a bit stuck since I don't know how to perform the same action.
Currently I have the following code

```
require 'caffe'
require 'image'
net = caffe.Net('/opt/caffe/models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/deploy.prototxt', '/opt/caffe/models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel')
img = image.lena()
dest = torch.Tensor(3, 227,227)
img = image.scale(dest, img)
img = img:resize(10,3,227,227)
output = net:forward(img:float())
conv_nodes = net:findModules('fc7') -- not working
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all please note that [torch-caffe-binding](https://github.com/szagoruyko/torch-caffe-binding) (i.e the tool you use with `require 'caffe'`) is a direct wrapper around Caffe library thanks to LuaJIT FFI.

This means that it allows you to conveniently do a forward or backward with a Torch tensor, **but** [behind the scenes](https://github.com/szagoruyko/torch-caffe-binding/blob/9b0892a/caffe.cpp#L30-L69) these operations are made on a `caffe::Net` and not on a Torch `nn` network.

So if you want to manipulate a plain [Torch network](https://github.com/torch/nn) what you should use is the [loadcaffe](https://github.com/szagoruyko/loadcaffe) library which fully converts the network into a [`nn.Sequential`](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/containers.md#nn.Sequential):

```
require 'loadcaffe'

local net = loadcaffe.load('net.prototxt', 'net.caffemodel')
```

Then you can use [`findModules`](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/module.md#findmodulestypename). However please note that you cannot use their initial label anymore (like `conv1` or `fc7`) as they are [discarded after convert](https://github.com/szagoruyko/loadcaffe/blob/7013690/loadcaffe.lua#L23-L40).

Here `fc7` (= `INNER_PRODUCT`) corresponds to the N-1 linear transformation. So you can get it as follow:

```
local nodes = net:findModules('nn.Linear')
local fc7 = nodes[#nodes-1]
```

Then you can read the data (weights and biases) via `fc7.weight` and `fc7.bias` - these are regular `torch.Tensor`-s.

---

**UPDATE**

As of commit [2516fac](https://github.com/szagoruyko/loadcaffe/commit/2516fac) loadcaffe now saves layer names in addition. So to retrieve the `'fc7'` layer you can now do something like:

```
local fc7
for _,m in pairs(net:listModules()) do
  if m.name == 'fc7' then
    fc7 = m
    break
  end
end
```

Comment: I was using the torch-caffe-binding because I was unable to use the loadcaffe. I get a ` loop or previous error loading module 'loadcaffe`

Comment: torch-caffe-binding will not let you (so far) read the layer data from Lua (basically all you can do is forward/backward from Torch tensors). So you really need loadcaffe!

Comment: Ok thank you I will try once again to install loadcaffe

Comment: loadcaffe is working if I download it from github and then I use luarocks make. Anyway thanks for your explanations

Comment: This is strange since the [official rockspec](https://github.com/torch/rocks/blob/47e4cdbf2a1ac128122744b43e0f59b4f5eaf1fd/loadcaffe-1.0-0.rockspec) is the same. I can't understand the problem you had with loadcaffe: perhaps this deserves an issue on GitHub?

Comment: @deltheil Is there a way that torch-caffe-binding's codes are slightly modified to extract the weights or bias?

Comment: @deltheil Do you know where can I find the corresponding `net.prototxt` and `net.caffemodel` files for `VGG16` network? I guess I have to download them before I call `loadcaffe.load()` method right?